# Nginx disable or decode url encoding when writing to access log

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have an open resty nginx with lua code that enhance the data and then I write this data to the access log for data analysis.
The data that the lua code produce includes double quotes but nginx write it to the access log as \x22.
Can I disable this behaviour or decode it back to "?

Comment: You can't. It's hardcoded in log module

Comment: OK. It is good to know. I will try other solutions.

Comment: Is there other way to send data from the lua code to the nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, you should write your comment as an answer. It is a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer you can't.
But, you can run an URL decode after logrotate.

Here is the command :

```
awk -v RS='\\\\x[0-9]{2}' 'RT{ORS=sprintf("%c", strtonum("0" substr(RT, 2)))} 1'
```